# 404 error for some internal sub-store pages in magento with nginx

Tags: nginx, magento, url-rewriting, magento2, nginx-location

I am not able to access some internal pages of my store, however disabling the **web/seo/use_rewrites** it works perfectly.

I think it is some nginx configuration that is not right, I tried to create a rewriter, but there are many locations.

- WORK: https://127.0.0.1/
- WORK: https://127.0.0.1/rj/
- WORK: https://127.0.0.1/sp/
- DONT WORK: https://127.0.0.1/rj/customer/account/forgotpassword/
- DONT WORK: https://127.0.0.1/sp/sociallogin/social/login/type/facebook/

Here is my conf:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}

server {

    listen 80 reuseport default_server;

    server_name  _;

    root /var/www;

    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
          rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ (index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php {
        fastcgi_pass    fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;

        fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=18000";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;        
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;  
    access_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log;
}
```

if i managed to put a rewriter adding an index.php after each folder sub-store, i think the problem would be solved.

I tried to create a rule to always add index.php, however it downloads instead of being executed.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
    rewrite ^/(\w*)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php/$2 last;
}
```

Comment: please check rewrite module enable in local or not?

Comment: Yes it is activated, so much so that the rules I created (even wrong ones) change the behavior of the application.

Comment: Can you show me .htaccess file?

Comment: I'm using nginx/1.17.8 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nginx reads the locations in the order in which they are written, so I needed to create a rule for the sub-store and I had to reorder it so that there would be no infinite loop of rules.

Here's what I did:

```
location ~ (index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php {
    fastcgi_pass    fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;

    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;        
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ ^/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ {
  try_files  $uri   $uri/ /$1/index.php/$2?$query_string;
}

location ~ .php/ {
      rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}
```